# Specs2 + Scalacheck test failing due to many discarded

Tags: specs2, scalacheck

In a ScalaCheck + Specs2 based test, I need two dates whose distance (in days) it's at maximum of Int.MAX_VALUE.

I am using at the moment ScalaCheck provided arbitraries to generating two dates: since the date generator is backed by the Long generator, this leads to too many discarded cases, making my test to fail.

What is the right approach to solve the problem:

- Shall I modify my generators or
- Shall I modify the test parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is probably to create your own generators for your domain.